# Powershell foreach loop isn't exiting on third execution

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach

I have a powershell script that loops through a SQL table of URLs and collects any further URLs in the  tags on the webpage.

It seems to work well when there is only a few URLs in the SQL table but the foreach loop seems to stop working after a few runs and the table has grown (but only to about 250+ rows), after that it just hangs and I can't figure out why. The activity simply stops and the foreach loop never exits.

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PowerScrape;trusted_connection=true;"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$SqlCommand.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlSelectStatement = ("SELECT URL as url FROM dbo.CapturedURL WHERE NOT LEFT(Url,7) ='mailto:'")
$SqlCommand.CommandText = $SqlSelectStatement
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCommand
$SqlCommand.Connection = $SqlConnection
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($Dataset)

ForEach ($Row in $Dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{

    $Request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Row[0] 
    $UrlArray = $Request.Links | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href 
    $UrlAuthority = $Request.BaseResponse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResponseUri | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Authority

    ForEach ($Url in $UrlArray) 
    {
        If ($Url -like "/*") 
        {
            $ScrapedUrl = $UrlAuthority+$Url 
        } 

        Else    
        {
            $ScrapedUrl = $Url
        }

        If ($ScrapedUrl -notlike "#*"-and $ScrapedUrl -ne '' -and $ScrapedUrl -ne $null)
        {
            $SqlInsertStatement = "
            BEGIN 
                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CapturedUrl WHERE URL = '"+$ScrapedUrl+"')
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT CapturedURL (URL) VALUES ('"+$ScrapedUrl+"')
                    END   
            END;"

        $SqlCommand = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
        $SqlCommand.CommandText = $SqlInsertStatement
        $SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        }
    }
}
```

When I insert one row in to my table, for example http://rouge.jneen.net (not my website, just one I like with only a few links to start off) a further six URLs are inserted. Then when I run it again it goes off to all the URLs in table and inserts 279 URLs. This is fine, but when I run it a third time it hangs after invoking the Invoke-WebRequest on Uri https://github.com/edwardloveall/portfolio and doesn't do anything else.

Can someone please point me in the direction of how to debug this or where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Did you try debugging your script in ISE? That should at least give you an indication. Using the Verbose switch in the command that hangs should tell you more after that.

Comment: Yeah I did, it iterated through and didn't throw any errors, but still didn't exit. When it came to the URL that it failed on running without debugging, it wouldn't let me step over, into or out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$Request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Row[0] -TimeoutSec 30
```

I had a similar Problem and the culprit was invoke,It kept waiting till the invoke happened.So give a timeout to the invokes to skip some the invokes that are eating up your time.

Also i suggest you to try Workflows and do this using[For eac Parallel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel) for faster execution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried setting the timeout to 2 seconds and left it for half an hour and it still didn't complete.

Comment: Okay ,As a rookie fix try to have a debugger and  set a lot of  variable inside foreach loop and try to figure out where exactly the code gets weird.I would suggest (if possible)Post the sample data in here,So we understand what exactly is going in it.